Usage of controller-level route
We have an API with a controller-level route defined like this:
[Route("api/[controller]")]

We also have method level routes defined like this:
[Route("/method_name/{version}")]

Now, what is the purpose of having the controller-level route when you have method-level routes defined? It seems that the leading slash in the method-level routes causes the controller-level route to be ignored causing a 404; meaning if we define the method-level route as
[Route("method_name/{version}")]

the route that works is
api/controller_name/method_name/{version}


For what you are trying to achieve, route should not be at method level. If you do this at method level it will work.
[HttpGet("GetCustBookingSummary/{version}")]
public CustSummaryData GetSummary(string version)


I was just asking is it needed. We currently call our API with routes like /method_name/{version}
